# How to Limit render element Flat List and add more content in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I want like that flatlist render only 5 checkbox items and then when I click to +5 more button it will show 5 more checkbox list.[In this all checkbox list appearing but i want only five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4gKK.png)

Please help me how to achieve that
Thanks in advance

```
 const renderResourceList = renderData => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={renderData}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                if(resourceTypeArray.includes(item)){
                  setResourceTypeArray(currentList => {
                    return currentList.filter(items => items !== item);
                  }); 
                }
                else{
                  setResourceTypeArray(currentList => [
                    ...currentList,
                    item
                  ]); 
                }
                  onSetResourceType(item);         
              }}
              style={styles.modalBtn}>
              <Icon
                name={
                  resourceTypeArray.includes(item) ? 'checkbox-marked' : 'checkbox-blank-outline'
                }
                size={18}
                color="#353C3C"
                style={{bottom: -1}}
              />

              <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.modalText}>{item.charAt(0)}
              {item.toLowerCase().slice(1).replace(/_/g, ' ')}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    );
  };
```

I tried but this not working

Comment: can you Give your full code ?

Comment: Have you tried to control renderData and not flatList behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I used a package called `flatlist-react` to handle this for me. A decent tutorial for this can be found [here](https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-data-lists-in-react-like-a-pro-flatlist-react-c5a82183d5b4).

With this package, you can directly specify and limit the items rendered with the limit prop. Here is an example:

```js
<FlatList
  limit="2,-2"
  list={people}
  renderItem={Person}
  />
```

If you keep track of the `limit` prop variables using state, you can dynamically change these values when you click `5+ more` in order to render whatever part of your data you would like.